# Algorithm to generate this alignment pattern locations table for QR codes

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking for a way to generate the following the series of numbers given the version number on the left. For example, given "2", generate [6, 18]. The series of numbers is from [the alignment pattern locations for different versions of QR codes](http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/alignment-pattern-locations/).

> ```
>  V2  6  18
>  V3  6  22
>  V4  6  26
>  V5  6  30
>  V6  6  34
>  V7  6  22  38
>  V8  6  24  42
>  V9  6  26  46
> V10  6  28  50
> V11  6  30  54
> V12  6  32  58
> V13  6  34  62
> V14  6  26  46  66
> V15  6  26  48  70
> V16  6  26  50  74
> V17  6  30  54  78
> V18  6  30  56  82
> V19  6  30  58  86
> V20  6  34  62  90
> V21  6  28  50  72   94
> V22  6  26  50  74   98
> V23  6  30  54  78  102
> V24  6  28  54  80  106
> V25  6  32  58  84  110
> V26  6  30  58  86  114
> V27  6  34  62  90  118
> V28  6  26  50  74   98  122
> V29  6  30  54  78  102  126
> V30  6  26  52  78  104  130
> V31  6  30  56  82  108  134
> V32  6  34  60  86  112  138
> V33  6  30  58  86  114  142
> V34  6  34  62  90  118  146
> V35  6  30  54  78  102  126  150
> V36  6  24  50  76  102  128  154
> V37  6  28  54  80  106  132  158
> V38  6  32  58  84  110  136  162
> V39  6  26  54  82  110  138  166
> V40  6  30  58  86  114  142  170
> ```

I've come up with the following Python code which generates the correct sequences, but contains an "exceptional" condition for V32, expressed in the `if` statement.

```
import math

def pattern(ver):
    w = 21 + ((ver - 1) * 4)       # Width
    h = 6                          # First item
    t = (w - 1) - 6                # Last item
    r = t - h                      # Distance between first and last
    n = math.ceil(r/28)            # Number of items in list - 1

    if (w == 145):
        intervals = 26             # Anomaly
    else:
        intervals = math.ceil(r/n) # Ceiling to nearest multiple of 2
        intervals = intervals + (intervals % 2)

    xs = [t]
    for m in (n-1) * [intervals]: xs.append(xs[-1] - m)
    xs.append(h)
    return list(reversed(xs))

for n in range(2, 41):
    print("Version {:2d}: {}".format(n, pattern(n)))
```

I'm looking for an algorithm where the magic branch & value is not needed The algorithm might not exist, but I'm hopeful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think such algorithm exists, because I looked quite hard and couldn't find it. It seems you have to follow the given table. Your formula approximates it pretty well. Too bad about the magic branch, but this shouldn't be a major concern anyway:
it's a small table that you only need to calculate once and can reuse later,
so any performance issues should be negligible in practice.

#### Coding style

The coding style can be improved.
Follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official coding style guide of Python,
for example, put 2 blank lines in front of top-level method definitions

#### Unnecessary parentheses

The parentheses around the multiplication are unnecessary here:

> ```
> w = 21 + ((ver - 1) * 4)       # Width
> ```

It would be better to use more meaningful variable names, 
for example no need to shorten `version` as `ver`.

Unnecessary parentheses here:

> ```
> if (w == 145):
> ```

#### The augmented assignment operator `+=`

Instead of:

> ```
>     intervals = intervals + (intervals % 2)
> ```

This is better:

```
    intervals += intervals % 2
```

#### Use one statement per line

Break the line after `:`, for example instead of:

> ```
> for m in (n-1) * [intervals]: xs.append(xs[-1] - m)
> ```

Write like this:

```
for m in (n-1) * [intervals]: 
    xs.append(xs[-1] - m)
```

#### Avoid code in the global namespace

Move code out of the global namespace into methods, so instead of this:

> ```
> for n in range(2, 41):
>     print("Version {:2d}: {}".format(n, pattern(n)))
> ```

Do it this way:

```
def main():
    for n in range(2, 41):
        print("Version {:2d}: {}".format(n, pattern(n)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

This thread is very old, so you may already know this: your algorithm can be modified to avoid the "magic branch". The modified version introduces one more branch, though.

```
import math

def pattern(ver):
    w = 21 + ((ver - 1) * 4)       # Width
    h = 6                          # First item
    t = (w - 1) - 6                # Last item
    r = t - h                      # Distance between first and last
    n = math.ceil(r/28)            # Number of items in list - 1

    intervals = r // n # Divide and get the quotient.

    if intervals % 2: # The quotient is odd -> make it even.
        intervals++
    elif (r % n) * 2 >= n: # The quotient is even -> round it to the next even.
        intervals += 2

    xs = [t]
    for m in (n-1) * [intervals]: xs.append(xs[-1] - m)
    xs.append(h)
    return list(reversed(xs))

for n in range(2, 41):
    print("Version {:2d}: {}".format(n, pattern(n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I also don't see any way to avoid the exceptional case.

Your variables should have better names.  If you avoid single-character names, then you could dispense with the comments.

The width formula could be simplified without losing any meaning.

The epilogue could also be simplified: repeatedly decreasing by a fixed interval is easily accomplished with `range()`.

```
from math import ceil

def pattern(version):
    width = 17 + 4 * version
    (first, last) = (6, width - 6 - 1)
    span = last - first
    n = ceil(span / 28)

    interval = 2 * ceil(span / n / 2)           # Round up to multiple of 2
    if width == 145:                            # except version 32:
        interval = 26                           # instead of 28

    return [first] + list(reversed(range(last, 2 * first, -interval)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for version in range(2, 41):
        print("Version {:2d}: {}".format(version, pattern(version)))
```